# How to integrate Shopify App into custom HTML Call to Action

Tags: html, css, shopify, shopify-app

I am building a `Shopify` store and have created my own custom Popup with `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS`. I also have an app on `Shopify` for sending emails, however, I want the app to send an email to a person when they submit their email via the popup, does anyone have any idea how to connect to an app in `Shopify` through my own custom `HTML` popup?

Thanks

Comment: What email app are you using?

Comment: I am using Kaviyo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pop up form is correctly configured to post the new contact to your Klaviyo subscriber list, you could accomplish this by having a Welcome Series setup. I did a quick Google search and found this [guide to setting up a Welcome Series](https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002775172-Create-a-Welcome-Series-Flow) with Klaviyo.